Difference between otel.service.name and otel.resource.attributes.service.name configuration
What is the difference between the otel.service.name and otel.resource.attributes.service.name configuration options? The docs are a bit confusing. The table specifies:

A resource is the immutable representation of the entity producing the telemetry. See resources for more details.
otel.service.name: Specify logical service name. Takes precedence over service.name defined with otel.resource.attributes.

And directly under the table:

Make sure to use otel.service.name to set the service.name resource attribute, which represents the logical name of your service. If unspecified, the SDK sets service.name=unknown_service:java by default.

Following the link to resources states the following:

There are attributes provided by the OpenTelemetry SDK. One of them is the service.name, which represents the logical name of the service. By default, SDKs will assign the value unknown_service for this value, so it is recommended to set it explicitly, either in code or via setting the environment variable OTEL_SERVICE_NAME.

Following the service.name resource attribute link leads to a table with the following information:

service.name    Logical name of the service. [1]    Required
[1]: MUST be the same for all instances of horizontally scaled services. If the value was not specified, SDKs MUST fallback to unknown_service: concatenated with process.executable.name, e.g. unknown_service:bash. If process.executable.name is not available, the value MUST be set to unknown_service.

Clicking service.name in the table leads to yet another table, which contains more attributes, but has the same description and note for service.name.
So my question boils down to this: Does that mean otel.service.name MUST be set? If it must be set and it takes precedence over the resource attribute, then why specify the resource attribute at all? Do I have to set both?
What's the difference between these two configuration settings:

otel.service.name=myservice
otel.resource.attributes.service.name=myservice

